# Real time activity monitoring for a Windows service

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services

I have a Windows service that currently outputs logging activity to either a text file or a database (depending on the activity).  What I would like to do is to have a way to run another process (probably an executable) that can connect to that service and receive activity updates from that Windows service using like a publish/subcribe approach.

In theory, I guess this can be done by hosting a socket connection on the Windows service and pushing activity data as it happens. I wonder though if there is s better approach? Is there maybe a framework that can do all this for me easily? Or maybe I should use a MQ product to broadcast the application activity?

I am using C# .net version 4.5

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways:

1. Socket is very good two-way communication
2. WCF is also another option, also two way communication support
3. Database - if you need to keep the history of the signals, you probably use one table where server/host inserts into a table and client reads from table using [SQL Dependency](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/detecting-changes-with-sqldependency). You can read new signals without timer or waiting, almost in real time.
4. Another good option is SignalR.

I have been using all technologies except WCF.